# Change the date format for the showLastUpdateTime at the bottom of pages

Tags: date, format, locale, docusaurus

I've added the

```js
          showLastUpdateTime: true,
```

line to my `docusaurus.config.js`, and the date is showing at the bottom of documents, but the format is US (which doesn't work for the majority of the world). I need it to be unambiguous, or not 'wrong' :D

Does anyone know how I can change this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can explicitly set the format manually - it uses the default [Intl.DateTimeFormat constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) under the hood - however you can manipulate it by setting the base locale of your site to something other than the default.

To do this, you need to leverage the [i18n configuration](https://docusaurus.io/docs/docusaurus.config.js#i18n) - add this to your `docusaurus.config.js`:

```
i18n: {
  defaultLocale: 'en-GB',
  locales: ['en-GB']
}
```

Substitute `en-GB` for whatever your desired locale is, and you'll see the date show in that locale's format, so in the UK it's `dd/MM/yyyy`.